# Flexbox: Centering element in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I'm going to center an element in the middle of the screen with **flexbox**, is the following approach the most elegant?

### HTML

```
<div class='btn'></div>
```

### CSS

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.btn{
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #033649;
  margin: auto;
}
```

It seems that I have to use `position: absolute` and **height+weight 100%** to achieve this.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to use position: absolute because the default for an element is position: relative, and in this case, there is nothing to be relative *to* because you have made the flex container the body.

Your code will work fine, but there is a command to center objects in the actual flex model itself like so:

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /*centers items on the line (the x-axis by default)*/
  align-items: center; /*centers items on the cross-axis (y by default)*/
}
```

If you do this you can remove the margin: auto from your .btn class to perhaps give some more wiggle room in your code.

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a good resource for all things flexbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can position an element inside a container by using **place-items** without the need to add any CSS property to that element. In this case I'm using the **body** of document as the container.

### Snippet

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  height:100vh; /* use 100% of the height of the viewport */
  display:grid;             
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button>I'm a lonely button :B</button>
</body>
```

### About place-items

> The CSS place-items shorthand property allows you to align items along
> both the block and inline directions at once (i.e. the align-items and
> justify-items properties) in a relevant layout system such as Grid or
> Flexbox. If the second value is not set, the first value is also used
> for it.

Find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items)