# Cannot align items to centre of page in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, alignment, bootstrap-5

I am trying to align an item to the centre of the page in html using bootstrap flex boxes. For some reason the align-items-centre attribute is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        elment goes here
    </div>
  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: this will be horizontally centered, do you want it vertically centered as well?

Comment: [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451293/flexbox-centering-element-in-the-middle-of-the-screen)

Comment: yes, I'd like to centre it horizontally and vertically so its in the middle of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to specify the height of your container, vertical alignment will not work without a height. You need to add `vh-100` for element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        element goes here
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

What are you trying to achieve? just one element in whole page? Here you go :D

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```